# Update records using EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to using EF to handle data in SQL. In a MVC Core project we're testing EF (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, version 2.2.3) to handle data.

When trying to update data and update failed for some reason (missing fields etc) it seemed like EF actually deleted the record from the database (MSSQL 2014) instead of throwing an update error...

Is it possible?

Code for updating:

```
public void Update(Contact contact)
        {
            _dbContext.Update(contact);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When trying to update data and update failed for some reason (missing fields etc) it seemed like EF actually deleted the record from the database (MSSQL 2014) instead of throwing an update error...*

*Is it possible?*

It should not.

test it, try to debug here

```
_dbContext.Update(contact); 
_dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
var updated = _dbContext.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == contact.Id); //debug here
```

check if it has a value, if still none, these are the scenarios i can think of that may have caused your problem

- investigate the missing field specially if it is not nullable.
- is the `_dbContext` used here is the same connection string used with everything?
- is the `[Key]` attribute listed on your `Contact` entity?

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id
}
```

- overridden the `SaveChanges` function?
- is what you are passing `Contact` contains a `Key` and it is not `0`?
- is a `delete` function called after `Update`?
- try using `SQL Profiler` to look at the `Linq to SQL` if it really generated an update query and if it is really pointing at the right `[Key]`

but if it is still not working properly, you could do

```
public void Update(Contact contact)
{
    var selectedContactToBeUpdated = _dbContext.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == contact.Id);

    if (selectedContactToBeUpdated != null)
    {
        selectedContactToBeUpdated.PropertyToBeUpdated1 = newValue;
        selectedContactToBeUpdated.PropertyToBeUpdated2 = newValue2;
        //additional Properties
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

in the scenario above, it will only generate an `Update` statement with fields you have changed.

Comment: The missing fields I had can both be NULL. So in what scenarios is it possible that EF would/will delete a record on failed update?

Comment: @TheMixy can you add if possible add `Contact` entity, image of db design, table before update and table after update

Comment: I have added the table design and highlighted the fields that were missing when it seemed like EF is deleting records

Comment: This is what I use for inserting:
 public void Add(Contact contact)
        {
            _dbContext.Add(contakt);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: I already have a solution (I will add validation on user input before updating)... The reason why I'm posting this question is to find out if its possible the EF behaves in such a manner and why, because it's incomprehensible that a record get's deleted when update fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198227/discussion-between-gab-llorico-and-themixy).

Comment: Issue cannot be reproduced. Maybe there were some problems with our test/development database